# Number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I saw this exercise:

> Prove that the number of group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ is $k=\gcd(m,n)$, where $m,n$ are natural numbers. If $m,n$ are prime to each other, then the only homomorphism is the trivial one.

I know that a homomorphism $t$ from $\mathbb{Z_n}$ to some other group $H$ matches an element $g\in H$ such that $g^n = e$, $t(1)=g$. How does the $gcd$ here take place and give the number of homomorphisms?

Comment: I added the information in the original post. I am looking for group homomorphisms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint 1:** If you know $f(1)$ you know $f$. Indeed
$$f(k)=kf(1) \forall k \in \mathbb Z$$

**Hint 2:** If $f(1)=a$ then 
$$0 =f(0)=f(m)=mf(1)=m a$$

Therefore
$$ma \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$

**Hint 3** Show that every $a$ which satisfies Hint 2 works.

Comment: From your hints I understand that there are $gcd(n,m)$ elements s.t. $ma = 0 (mod n)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z_n}$?

Comment: @TheNotMe Let $d=\gcd(m,n)$, and $m=dm_1, n=dn_1$. Then $n|ma \Leftrightarrow n_1|m_1a \Leftrightarrow n_1|a$. Now write $a=kn_1$, how many choices do you have for $k$ ? ;)